# Laravel: belongsTo not working when changing it's function name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5

I have this relation `Artist - has many - Album`

Artist class:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Artist extends Model {

  public function albums()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Album');
  }

}
```

Album class:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Album extends Model {

  public function artist()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App/Artist');
  }

}
```

If I do this: `$album->artist` there's no problem at all

But if I change the function's name inside Album class without changing the model/class name:

```
public function artistInfo()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Artist');
}
```

Then, this won't work: `$album->artistInfo`. It returns `null` for me

P.S. This is not my real schema but the problem only appears when I change the function's name of the belongsTo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, I found the proper answer and it turns out that it's an easy one.

In the relationship function specify the keys (foreign key and local key). For this example:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Album extends Model {

  public function artistInfo()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App/Artist','artist_id','id');
  }

}
```

Now you can do it as usual:  `$artist->artistInfo` or `Album::find(1)->artistInfo->name`

Comment: Adding the foreign key argument alone is enough to solve the problem, unless your primary key is named something other than "id".

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent, the ORM used in Laravel is designed to be model based, and give a real world object definition.  As such, and from my experience, it's not possible to change these.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take the answer above(?), but you can do what I believe you're asking with

`Album.php`

```
public static function getAlbum($id)
{
    return static::with(['artistInfo'])->find($id);
}

public function artistInfo()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Artist');
}
```

and in `AlbumController.php`

```
use App\Album;

public function single($id)
{
    $album = Album::getAlbum($id);

    return $album->artistInfo;
}
```

Hope this is of some help. At the very least, have you checked any `with()` statements for the appropriate name change?

Answer (score 0):

Use any name of your function. Just add additional value of what is the relational `attribute name` of of that model(table) in this table.

```
 public function artistInfo()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Artist::class,'artist_id');
  }
```